# Flutter app gets stuck at "Automatically signing iOS..." while running

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run my flutter app on my iphone. When I run and debug it, it stays on

```
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project
```

And it doesn't continute. It stays stuck there. I tried running flutter clean, but it still didn't work. (The last thing I did was added `cloud_firestore`.

**Update:**

Just noticed that when I remove `cloud_firestore`, it works, but the package doesn't fully get installed, and I don't have access to all the firestore functionality

Comment: Have you tried opening your project in XCode and running from there? Sometimes that gives better Error messages.

Comment: @BenediktJSchlegel I'm getting this error in xcode: `The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation`

Answer (score 1):

As Benedikt mentioned, opening Runner.xcworkspace often works better for running your app.  What fixed it for me was removing all developer accounts from the keychain and then adding the account again in Xcode.

Comment: I'm getting this error in xcode: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation